# Keyboard-type (e.g. "EN") doesn't show up for Windows under Parallels

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, parallels

I recently installed Parallels Desktop for Mac so that I could run Windows programs on my Mac. 
Unfortunately, when I add new Keyboards to Windows 7 (Control Panel >> Clock, Language and Region >> Change Keyboards or Other Input Methods >> Change Keyboard), I sucesfully add the keyboard, but up at the top of my screen on the Mac Menu bar where all of my notification icons should be, there is no icon for the current keyboard (on a regular Windows machine there would be an EN or CH (chinese)).

How do I get the Keyboard Icon to show up so that I can easily change Keyboards? (left) Alt - Shift doesn't work.